# How can i set the az monitor command to get time period data in Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I use the Az cmd below

```
az monitor metrics list --resource <resourceid>  --metrics "CpuPercentage"
```

This give metrics for the last hour. Is there any parameters i can add to get the average over a small period e.g. 5 minutes and check if that exceeds a threshold (usually 75-80%) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can give time interval like below, which gives average usage of CPU in last 5 minutes but for each minutes.

```
az monitor metrics list --resource <resourceId> --metric 'Percentage CPU' --interval PT1M --start-time $(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ" --date='5 minutes ago') --end-time $(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ" --date='0 minute ago') --aggregation Average
```

Please find examples here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/metrics?view=azure-cli-latest

To find a threshold that exceeds certain limit you need to set an alert. Please find more about that here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/metrics/alert/condition?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: i use the following:   az monitor metrics list --resource <resourceid> --metric 'Percentage CPU' --interval PT1M --start-time $(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") --end-time $(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") --aggregation Average But get the error :  az : ERROR: (BadRequest) End time: 11/16/2022 2:02:35 AM must be at least 1 minute later than start time: 11/16/2022 2:02:35 AM

Comment: Also that command above , az monitor metrics list  get the metric for the App Service Plan. If there are lets say 3 App Services in the App Service Plan and one is causing the high CPU , how can i identify that ? Is there a command that can be used for the App Service that brings back the CPU and Memory usage ?